# Line Break in Facebook Messenger using Python

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I am using python and I am trying to make a line break in Facebook messenger. From previous answers to this questions I saw that

```
text = “text string <center></center> new line”
```

should work. It is not working for me. Any ideas how I can solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\n` works on mobile and web. `\r` also works, but appears to be a bug where it doesn't work on web.